# I want to see the main code of the plugin discordSRV but whenever i open the jar file, its displaying weird set of characters

Tags: java, visual-studio, encoding

I downloaded the [DiscordSRV](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/discordsrv.18494/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_d0o.HvIslLKcxHIRXDNfJnNG.PVyI9u6MW4eXWuZ_eY-1634919871-0-gqNtZGzNAjujcnBszQml) jar file which is a minecraft plugin. But whenever i am opening the file it is showing these weird set of characters ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djc6M.png)), but i want to see the main code of that file. I am opening it using VS code and before opening the it, VS code is showing me a prompt message 'The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses unsupported text encoding'. Is there any way to resolve this? I am actually new to programming.. so please explain what i need to do in a simple way, I would be very grateful! Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

**JAR** files use the **ZIP** format and usually contain compiled classes (**.class** files) and resources

The former contain **bytecode** generated by the Java compiler, they **don't** contain the **source code**

The **source code** of the project can be seen here https://github.com/DiscordSRV/DiscordSRV